# Volley POST request Android token

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am new to new android programming and currently working with the Volley POST request library for a login page. I already have a working API which gives a String token when you make a post request. For now I have hard coded the username and password just to see if the post request works by creating a Toast. However, when I click on the submit button it prints out 200 in toast which doesnt make sense because the token is very big. It takes a few seconds for the toast to appear. This is what the API gives(I need the token):

```
{
         "status": true,

         "result": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.rU3NIqiHxsgOS7zeeuSCmPZP9Sc7RMXVGKWXni4JBLM"
    }
}
```

Here is the current code that I have :

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username, password;
Button loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    this.username = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    this.password = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    this.loginButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    this.loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "I just clicked the button", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                RequestQueue requestQueue = 
  Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                String URL = 
 "http://apidev.travelhouse.world/api/v1/user/login? 
username=faisalckyf@gmail.com&password=faisal";
                final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
 //                    jsonBody.put("username", "faisalckyf@gmail.com");
 //                    jsonBody.put("password", "faisal");
                final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new 
  JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new 
 Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    String token = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                        {
                            try {
                                JSONObject hit = 
response.getJSONObject(i);
                                 token = hit.getString("token");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, token, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : 
requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while 
trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                protected Response<String> 
parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                      String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {
                        responseString = 
String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                        // can get more details such as response.headers
                    }
                        return Response.success(response, 
HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }

                    @Override
                    public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        headers.put("X-API-KEY", "CODEX@123");
                        return headers;
                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
 //
    });
 //
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing status code instead of result token in your `parseNetworkResponse()` function:

```
                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        String responseString = "";
                        if (response != null) {
                            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                            // can get more details such as response.headers
                        }
                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
```

You need to change the return statement to this:

```
return Response.success(response, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
```

As you can see, in your function you are taking the response but you are only passing the status code(`responseString`) to result.

Secondly your response is actually JSON object. You need to parse it to JsonObject (or use JsonObjectRequest) and then read value `token` nested in `result`.

Comment: Forgive me for being dumb but what do I change in parseNetworkResponse()? I am not sure what that method does. Should I iterate over the objects in the onResponse() to get the token?

Comment: its giving me an error on the return statement u edited.  return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)); I changed the String to JsonObject like u said. Could you check my code and see if I did it right?

Comment: @Imran you are still passing `responseString`, replace it with `response`